# Why has this question been upvoted 9 times?

Tags: discussion

I wonder why [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68415/google-indexing-pages-with-although-we-dont-have-any) been upvoted 9 times at this point. I looked into this issue and it seems like the website has some issues (it seems they are  cloaking) and I don't think this question is going to lead anywhere.

Is it upvoted because there is some detail and it has a bounty and people don't really check what's behind the question or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

There could be some vote fraud on the question, but there are other issues at play.

- The questions has nearly 300 views.  It doesn't seem to be unreasonable that 9 people out of 300 might upvote.
- There is a bunch of discussion in the comments.  To me that is a sign that real people have spent time on the question.
- Google's [John Mueller](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/711/john-mueller) commented there.   Any time there is a comment from a Google employee, it may be worth an upvote just for that comment.
- It seems like the kind of bug or problem that could effect many websites.

Comment: To prevent a meta loop, let me just say that I upvoted the question and this answer because I thought they were good.

Comment: Looks like the downvoted answer with the comment from Mueller has been deleted...

Comment: Yes, the poster deleted their own answer.  Likely because it was being down voted.  If they had waited for a few more down votes first they could have earned the "peer pressure" badge.